# Geckoview Doesn't work

Tags: android-studio, gecko

I am working on a project using geckoview in android studio. The app keeps crashing when I reach the containing activity. using log cat I found out that it gives me the following error

```
    FATAL EXCEPTION: main

    Process: app, PID: 2815

  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{project name}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #27: Binary XML file line #27: Error inflating class org.mozilla.gecko.GeckoView
```

I dont know how to fix this or what does it mean or what to do...
Here is my code, I hope it helps

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_page);
        Button Nav=(Button) findViewById(R.id.Nav);


        GeckoView geckoView = (GeckoView) findViewById(R.id.geckoview);


        GeckoSession session = new GeckoSession();
        geckoView.setSession(session);


        session.loadUri("http://google.com");


    }
```

XML

```
<org.mozilla.gecko.GeckoView
    android:id="@+id/geckoview"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="82dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/guideline2" />
```

Thank you in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Change Geckoview in xml as below

```
<org.mozilla.geckoview.GeckoView
    android:id="@+id/geckoview"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="82dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/guideline2" />
```

Comment: namespace app is not bound?